# How can I write curly capital Greek letters

Tags: greek

How can I write curly capital Greek letters, looking like math cal?
In particular I need curly `\Pi`. 
I want to have both version regular `\Pi` and curly `\Pi` in one text.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Could you please include a image to get an idea for all ?. As new user without image posting privileges simply include the image as normal and remove the `!` in front of it to turn it into a link. A moderator or another user with edit privileges can then reinsert the `!` to turn it into an image again.

Comment: Can you point to a resource showing the shape you have in mind?

Comment: \pi creates a smaller but curly/fancy pi greek letter. Is this what you had in mind?

Comment: Some of the greek letters have "variants", such as the, I believe to be a caligraphic variant, \varpi. I'm unaware of any such for the capital ones though.